# calculate entropy in dipoles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Can someone help me with this question.
I have a paramagnet with $N=1000$ dipoles.

I have to calculate the entropy for the macrostate where two of dipoles point upwards.

I was thinking about using $S = K \log(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ ? $( e q/N)^N$, but I don't know what my $q$ is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $1000$ dipoles. $2$ of them point up. But which two? Well, you can **choose** any two of them to be up and that microstate will describe the same macrostate. Hope fully that hint is enough for you to find the degeneracy, $\Omega$, of your macrostate.

Comment: is it like this: Omega(2) = (1000*999)/ 2

Comment: I solved it, thank you for your help!! I tried to upvote u, but I need 15 rep points ://

Comment: @tonytouch +1 now you can  sleep soundly

Comment: Good work! You can try to generalize this to the case of having $N$ dipoles, and $n\le N$ of them are up, the rest are down. In this case you will need to use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation to get a nice analytical result.